# Dynamodb localhost:8000 connection failing due to proxy error

Tags: localhost, amazon-dynamodb, http-proxy

I am able to start Dynamodb locally using this command-

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

I get following response to the above command-

```
    Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:       false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:       true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams:     *
```

However, when I enter below command on AWS CLI to set local endpoint-

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

I am getting below error-

```
  An error occurred (504) when calling the ListTables operation (reached max retries: 9): <HTML>
    <HEAD><TITLE>The Proxy Was Unable to Fulfill Your Request</TITLE></HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <H1>The Proxy Was Unable to Fulfill Your Request</H1>
    <HR SIZE="1">
    <P>The proxy was unable to fulfill your request because it could not contact the computer at localhost:8000 (Connection reset by peer).</P>
    <P>The website may be temporarily unavailable. If later attempts to access this website are still unsuccessful, you may wish to contact the website's adminis
    tor.
    </P>
<HR SIZE="1">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

MY PC's native proxy is set up to bypass local addresses including localhost. I tried setting AWS HTTP and HTTPS proxy using CLI as well. But it did not work. I then tried to use AWS Eclipse Plugin and using it, I can connect to the dynamodb on localhost (through Eclipse only, NOT from the CLI). I want to be able to use CLI for working with local dynamodb.

Please help.

Thanks,
Kunal

Comment: Can you open the url http://localhost:8000/shell in browser?

Comment: @notionquest Yes I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding following Windows Environment Variables-

```
HTTP_PROXY = http://<My-Proxy-Host>:<My-Proxy-Port>
HTTPS_PROXY = http://<My-Proxy-Host>:<My-Proxy-Port>
NO_PROXY= localhost
```

It is important to **Reboot** the PC to reflect these settings.

Hope it helps someone in need.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see the table list, please execute the below script on http://localhost:8000/shell/

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

var params = {
};

function doPrint(response) {
    if (response.error) ppJson(response.error); // an error occurred
    else {
        ppJson(response.data); // successful response
    }
}


console.log("List of tables");
dynamodb.listTables(params)
    .on('complete', doPrint)
    .send();
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see the table list using JS shell. Is there any way to use Non-JS shell?

Comment: As you have some proxy setup on your machine, it is little difficult to debug or suggest solution. My answer is to provide an alternative for it rather than solving the proxy issue. If you need CLI issue on your machine to be resolved for some other purpose, you may need to find other solution.

Comment: I agree. I will try other solutions.